# Two classes in the same package in different modules or different JARS

Tags: java, maven

```
// A.java
package com.example.www;

public class A {}

// B.java
package com.example.www;

public class B {
    A a;
}
```

In the above example, class B can create a reference to class A without ever importing A, because they are in the same package. But what if classes A and B had the same fully-qualified package name, but existed in different modules in a multi-module Maven project? Or, another scenario, what if the .class files for A and B were in different JARs?

Would classes A and B still have the same access to each other?

Answer (score 0):

If they are in different jars, you need to add import statements or access the classes using fully qualified names(assume class A is in package com.examples.etc).

```
import com.examples.etc.A

public class B {
 A a;
 }
```

or

```
public class B {
 com.examples.etc.A a;
}
```